# CLNDR.js selectedDate on first click is null

Tags: clndr.js

I'm trying to get the selected date on my calendar, but at the first click the selectedDate is null, it works only after secondclick. How can I get the selected Date on first click?

```
clickEvents: {
    click: function(target) {
        // console.log(target.date);
        console.log('1')
        temp1 = this.options;
        // selecionado = this.options.selectedDate;
        // xx = this.options;
        console.log('options');
        console.log(this.options);
        console.log('2');
        console.log('selectedDate')
        console.debug(this.options.selectedDate);
        console.log('targets')
        console.log(this.options.targets);
        console.log('options')
        console.log(this.options);
        console.log('3');
        selecionado = moment(target)
    },
},
```

my pen:

https://codepen.io/waltindead/pen/oyJdoN?editors=1111

Comment: Hi @Walter, did you ever find the solution to your problem? I am struggling with the same.